# how to replace a placeholder across a full HTML page using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, string, jquery-mobile, replace

I have an HTML demo page, whichs contain a placeholder "||*client*||". It's used throughout the page for example:

```
<img src="images/||_client_||/img1.jpg" />
```

or

```
<title>||_client_|| Demo</title>
```

and so on.

I want to globally replace the palceholder with the respective client ID once the page loads. The page is just for demo-purposes so I don't want to set up anything server side.

I'm binding to this:

```
 $('div:jqmData(role="page")').on('pagebeforecreate', function() {  
  // replace ||_client_|| with some ID      
  });
```

**Question:**
Is there a Jquery method to run through the DOM and find all instances of my placeholder and replace them or do I have to do each one by hand and look for all img tags, check the src for substring and replace this substring? There must be a nicer way?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to do this server-side? Or are you with static HTML?

Comment: It's a static mockup. Only the placeholder will change

Comment: Don't think there's a one-stop solution for that. You'd have to iterate through each possible setup (atrributes, html, ?) and use something like `.replace()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need jQuery?

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\|\|_client_\|\|/g, 'your text here');
```

---

For the entire page:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
html.innerHTML = html.innerHTML.replace(...);
```

---

As a word of caution, make sure you do this after the page is ready (so that the body has all the elements), and before you bind events to any elements.

Comment: doesn't have to be jquery, so this also looks nice. Any way to include the document head (some link elements I also need to change)

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML`, or `document.head.innerHTML` & `document.body.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 3):

You could scroll through each `<img />` object on the page and just do a search/replace.

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').on('pagebeforecreate', function() { 

    $('img').each(function(){
        var newVal = $(this).attr('src').replace('||_client_||', theClientId);
        $(this).attr('src', newVal);
    });

});
```

Instead of using `$('img')`, however, I would suggest refining the selector to only loop through the images in a specific div `$('#theDiv img')` or of a certain class `$('img.placeholder')`. The class option is probably the best. You would just need to add `class="placeholder"` to each image you want to be looped through.

Comment: I like the idea of bundling... this should work for <img> and <link> tags alike, shoudn't it?

Comment: This will work for any entity type that has a `src` attribue.

Answer (score 1):

actually you can do it like this:

```
//getting the html dom as string
var myStr = $("body").html();
//use reguler expression to replace your placeholder
myStr = myStr.replace(/\|\|\_client\_\|\|/gi,"Fareed");
//return it back to the dom
$("body").html(myStr);
```

note: /gi is for global and insensitive case

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that will replace all '||*client*||' with "replace_string" in the entire document.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>||_client_|| Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>||_client_||</h1>
        <img src="images/||_client_||/img1.jpg" />       
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.split('||_client_||').join('replace_string');
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your entire page to html using the .html() function, then replace your placeholder and set the resulting back using .html(). This will probably not be very performant, but it might work for you.

```
// Suppose we have a div with a test class: <div class="test">{PLACEHOLDER} title</div>
var div = $('.div')
var src = $(div).html()
src = src.replace('{PLACEHOLDER}', 'Test')
div.html(src)

// Your div now contains: <div class="test">Test title</div>
```

Good luck!